DuckDB not able to do multiple queries (using multiple connections) concurrently in Node.js
Im using DuckDb with the official Node.js library.
I'm trying to do multiple queries concurrently by opening multiple connections.
The timing of the results suggests that all queries are done sequentially instead of concurrently regardless of using multiple connections or not. See below code.
What could be the issue?
  //////////
  // Doing 10 parallel queries (queries is an array with queries out of context) using 1 Connection
  const totalSingleDT = Date.now()
  const queriesSingleConnection = _.map(queries, (query, i) => {
    const startDT = new Date()
    return config.db.all(query).then(rows => {
      console.log(`query single connection took (ms): ${Date.now() - startDT} rows: ${rows.length}`)
    })
  })
  await Promise.all(queriesSingleConnection)
  console.log(`Single total result took (ms): ${Date.now() - totalSingleDT}`)
  console.log("#############")


  //////////
  // Doing 10 parallel queries (queries is an array with queries out of context) using 10 Connections
  const connections = await Promise.all(_.map(_.times(10), () => config.db.connect()))

  const totalParallelDT = Date.now()
  const queriesMultipleConnections = _.map(queries, (query, i) => {
    const startDT = new Date()
    return connections[i].all(query).then(rows => {
      console.log(`query parallel connection took (ms): ${Date.now() - startDT} rows: ${rows.length}`)
    })
  })
  await Promise.all(queriesMultipleConnections)
  console.log(`Parallel total result took (ms): ${Date.now() - totalParallelDT}`)

Results
query single connection took (ms): 8 rows: 95
query single connection took (ms): 14 rows: 46
query single connection took (ms): 21 rows: 46
query single connection took (ms): 27 rows: 978
query single connection took (ms): 35 rows: 4397
query single connection took (ms): 39 rows: 135
query single connection took (ms): 45 rows: 328
query single connection took (ms): 51 rows: 35
query single connection took (ms): 58 rows: 45
query single connection took (ms): 63 rows: 71
Single total result took (ms): 63
#############
query parallel connection took (ms): 7 rows: 95
query parallel connection took (ms): 13 rows: 46
query parallel connection took (ms): 19 rows: 46
query parallel connection took (ms): 26 rows: 978
query parallel connection took (ms): 35 rows: 4397
query parallel connection took (ms): 39 rows: 135
query parallel connection took (ms): 45 rows: 328
query parallel connection took (ms): 51 rows: 35
query parallel connection took (ms): 57 rows: 45
query parallel connection took (ms): 63 rows: 71
Parallel total result took (ms): 64

